Decomposition of a matrix based on vector orthogonality criteria
Given a vector $u\in\mathbb R^{n}$, $u=Wx$, where $x\in\mathbb R^{m}$ and $W$ is a matrix of appropriate dimensions. Let $v\in\mathbb R^{n}$ be a fixed unit vector. I can decompose $u$ into $\perp$ vectors $a$ and $b$ such that
$$a=\lambda v \text{ and } b^\top v=0$$
Let there be some matrices $W_v$ and $W_b$ such that $a=\lambda W_vx$ and $b=W_bx$, then
$$u=Wx=(\lambda W_v+W_b)x$$
Given some choice of $W$, $x$ and $v$, I want to find an expression for $\Vert W_b\Vert_F$. Is the information sufficient for finding it?
A trivial case is when $u^\top v=0$, then $\Vert W_b\Vert_F=\Vert W\Vert_F$. Another extreme is when $u=\lambda v$, then $\Vert W_b\Vert_F=0$. So far I only have,
$$\Vert W_b\Vert_F\leq\Vert W\Vert_F$$
